# How can I use DISTINCT with a JOIN?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have those two tables:
`users`:
[image: users]

And `playertimes`:
[image: playertimes]

(I know `jumps` and `style` should be `int` and not `varchar()` but that's not what I'm trying to solve)

I have a query, which is supposed to return the following results within the resultset:

1. `name` - retrieved using `JOIN` with `auth`
2. `time`
3. `style`

Here's my current query:
`SELECT p.style, p.time, u.name FROM playertimes p JOIN users u ON p.auth = u.auth WHERE p.map = 'bhop_good' ORDER BY p.time ASC;`

Here's the result I'm getting with the query above:
[image: current query result]

At this moment, the table can only contains two possible values of `style` which are `0` or `1`. What I'm looking for, is to make `style` a `DISTINCT`, so in my case, I want to only get 2 results (one row per a value of `style`) for the query above, which should look like the following screenshot:

[image: ideal resultset]

I'd like to receive help, thanks!

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12113699/get-top-n-records-for-each-group-of-grouped-results

Comment: And consider using an unsigned integer to identify an user inside a db: it requires less space and it's much easier to handle with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want the `style` row for each distinct value of `style` having the smallest `time` value.

You get that like so. It takes two steps. The first determines the smallest time for each value

```
          SELECT style, MIN(time) time
            FROM playertimes
           GROUP BY style
```

The second step gets the actual `playertimes` row corresponding to that time.

```
    SELECT p.style, s.time, p.auth
      FROM playertimes p
      JOIN (
          SELECT style, MIN(time) time
            FROM playertimes
           GROUP BY style
           ) s ON p.style = s.style AND p.time = s.time
```

Finally, you can join that lot to your `users` table to turn your `auth` column into a `name` column.

```
    SELECT p.style, s.time, u.name
      FROM playertimes p
      JOIN (
          SELECT style, MIN(time) time
            FROM playertimes
           GROUP BY style
           ) s ON p.style = s.style AND p.time = s.time 
      JOIN users.u ON p.auth = u.auth
```

And, of course, once you have a working query you can add a WHERE clause to it, like this one.

```
    WHERE p.map = 'some constant'
```